# Shell script for cloning a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to make a shell script that has 2 arguments, each one a valid directory. The script makes a new directory in the first directory specified by the first argument with the same name as the second one and copies the content(both subdirectories and files) of the second one in the newly created directory. But it only copies the files with .txt extension.

This is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! $# -eq 2 ]
then echo usage: file.sh directory1 directory2
     exit 1
fi
if [ !  -d $1  ]
then echo $1 is not a directory \!
     exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $2 ]
then echo $2 is not a directory \!
     exit 1
fi
```

Comment: How about `cp -a`? See the [`cp` manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp).

Comment: The filter part is the one that's bugging me

Comment: No filtering, just do `cp -a directory1 directory2` and everything, including sub-directories, from `directory1` will be copied to `directory2`.

Comment: Have you thought about using `rsync` with suitable includes and excludes?

Comment: Consider using `cp -p` to keep the permissions of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving debugging to the student:

```
die () { echo >&2 "$*"; echo "Usage...."; exit 1; }
from="$1";
to="$2";
[ ."$from" = . ] && die "from dir name missing";
[ ."$to" = . ] && die "to dir name missing";
[ -d "$from" ] || die "from dir $from not a directory";
[ -d "$to" ] || die "to dir $to not a directory";
target="$to/$(basname "$from")";  #final target dir name, if I understand you correctly.
find "$from" -name '*.txt' -maxdepth=1 | cpio -pd "$to" ||
# (cd "$from" && find * -name '*.txt' -maxdepth=1 | cpio -o...) | ( cd "$to" && cpio -i...) ||
   die "cpio failed"
```

Beware that cpio has many options and you should review them before using it.

The commented out technique allows you to more freely move to alternate target directories, which I do not think you need here.

Avoid grief: always quote file names.

Answer (score 0):

Simply append this at the and of your script:

```
    cp -dR $2 $1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a better chance using [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

For example:

```
rsync -avz /dir1/ /dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your preferences about conservation of file properties, many one-liner alternatives exist around `cp`, `tar` or `rsync`. Filtering can be obtained using the `find`command.